# any way to recover lost qt bitcoin wallet?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, lost-bitcoins

Hi is there any way to recover my Bitcoin-Qt wallet with only an address and the wallet password? Unfortunately my disk was formatted.

Answer (score 2):

> Hi is there any way to recover my Bitcoin-Qt wallet with only an address and the wallet password?

No. I can't think of a secure way for the Bitcoin developers to add recovery method like that, either.

> Unfortunately my disk was formatted.

Do you mean that the space containing your wallet was overwritten, or that the space at the front of the disk that tells your computer how to read the disk was changed?

If it's the second one, your Bitcoins might be recoverable.

Comment: *I can't think of a secure way for the Bitcoin developers to add recovery method like that, either.* If it were a deterministic/HD wallet like Armory, Electrum, etc. then you could. But the way Bitcoin Core works, no, you can't recover it without the wallet.

Comment: As nick said, if it's just that the FAT (file allocation table, like an index) is formatted STOP using the HDD immediately and seek backup services

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot retrieve your funds just by having the bitcoin address that "holds" them and the wallet password.

You need to use a specialized utility that will try to recover chunks of your formatted disk to their previous state: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/251/file-recovery-software You then need to look for a file named: "wallet.dat". If you recover it successfully you will be able to retrieve your lost funds.